# How to use jQuery .load so that it pulls in an element after all scripts have finished running?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

I am currently using **datatables.js** to provide a directory on a WordPress site: `example.com/directory`.

I added the ability to filter the directory using a querystring so I can create links that when loaded show a subset of the directory: `example.com/directory/?search=query`.

Here is the code I am using on the directory page:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&#038;]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (!results)
        {
            return '';
        }
        return unescape(results[1]) || '';
    }

    jQuery('#directory').dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, -1], [15, 30, "All"]],
         "iDisplayLength" : 15,
         "oSearch": {"sSearch": jQuery.urlParam('search')}
         }).rowGrouping()

    jQuery('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
});
// ]]></script>
```

And for a page to that includes a subset of the directory: `example.com/departmentpage`.

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#result").load("http://example.com/directory/?search=departmentname #directory > *");
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The `.load` function works but it pulls in the entire raw table, not the table as it normally looks on the main directory page.  My assumption is that the `.load` function is pulling the `#directory` before the scripts run.

Is there a way to make `.load` wait until the scripts on the included page have run before it pulls the content into the includer page?

Comment: My initial thought is to make sure the script you want to run last is at the end of your script string.  Otherwise, put your `.load()` into a function and run it at the end of your last script?  I know there are better ways to make it wait, and I'm sure someone will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pulling `#directory > *` with `.load()`. If the script required to render the HTML you are pulling in is not contained in your `.load()` statement, nothing will happen. You will only be pulling raw HTML in.

You need to either include the script, or pull in the HTML via a different method and re-run the javascript needed to convert the table to its desired affect.

Upon initial inspection of the plugin you are using, I would recommend trying to use the `sAjaxSource` method to grab your data.

Comment: Eventually, perhaps 9-12 months from now the directory will likely be pulling from Active Directory instead of the current manually maintained table.  I've considered moving the current data from the table it is currently in into a json datasource, like this: [link]http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html and then use that datasource for any instances needed but I wanted to try and use what's already there if possible.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you may be at a loss in the current form, since it needs to actually ingest the data in to the plugin to display it properly. You can easily set up a .php endpoint and uses a `WP_Query` or such to spit out a JSON string that you can use with the plugin to consume the data and feed it in to the table.

Comment: Thank you, @tr3online.  I will convert the existing table data into a json data source and use it instead of what I've done so far.  It was very helpful to hear your opinion.